# Rule engine in Python

Tags: python, rule-engine

I'm writing some system which uses a lot of rules. It's time for me to organize them and make them efficient. Main requirements are - business friendly, easy to understand, easy to find, easy to maintain, testable.

This question is not about how to create rule engine. I'm not writing one. My goal is to find way to maintain lot of rules in one place. and make it easy. I need some expertise advice how to do so, what approach to take. Below are examples what I did already to show that I'm working on this task and not simply ask somebody to do my job.

So far I have 3 approaches:

1) **Array typed**:

```
item=context.GetNextItem()
if ['banana','apple','orange'].Contains(item): EatRaw(item)
if ['banana','apple','potato'].Contains(item): BakeAndEat(item)
if ['meat','egg','potato','fish'].Contains(item): FryAndEat(item)
if ['pasta','egg','potato'].Contains(item): BoilAndEat(item)
```

2) **Separated file for each item**:

```
item=context.GetNextItem()
execfile(str(item)+'.py') 

#banana.py:
EatRaw(item)
BakeAndEat(item)

#potato.py:    
BakeAndEat(item)
FryAndEat(item)
BoilAndEat(item)
```

3) **Database stored**:

```
item=context.GetNextItem()
SQL = "SELECT rule FROM rules where item='"+str(item)+"';"
for row in cursor.execute(SQL):
    eval( row.rule+"(str("+item+"))" )
```

Table RULES

```
banana,EatRaw
banana,BakeAndEat
potato,BakeAndEat
potato,FryAndEat
potato,BoilAndEat
```

3.a) **Data in file**

File RULES.txt

```
banana,EatRaw
banana,BakeAndEat
potato,BakeAndEat
potato,FryAndEat
potato,BoilAndEat
```

This file could be considered as a UI.

Each approach has it's own cons and pros but, to be honest, I'm not satisfied with any. Files grow, became bulky, hard to search, maintain and understand. Any other approach or suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Thanks. It's not code question, it's approach question.

Comment: @larsks: Code Review is explicitly *not* for questions about "higher-level architecture and design of software systems", which I believe this question is about.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: And yet, neither is here, only more so.  It was the best suggestion I had.

Answer (score 2):

Lets zoom in on this statement:

> Main requirements are - business friendly, easy to understand

However, your approaches so far are easy for *programmers* to understand, but not particularly easy for *business users* to understand.

You are approaching this problem from the wrong direction, you are starting with the "which datastructure is good for ergonomics", rather than "How business will users view or modify the 'rules'"

Start with a good few rounds of UI design.  Once you've got those, put it in front of potential users (if you have any), then the implementation will follow naturally, whichever closely models or supports the way the resulting UI works and is used.

edit:

a "ui" need not be a fancy single page javascript application, it can be a text file on a particular network share that gets read every day by a cron job,  that's still a "user interface".  Design that in a way that is compatible with both the business users needs and the available budget.

Comment: I totally agree. If it is system for sale then I'd do this. However when it's for internal use then creating UI is overkill. I'd love to do it but I'm not sure business will pay for it. Clear and understandable code without too many "programmer's" features would be good enough. Again, I totally agree that UI or DCL or real Rule Engine would be better...But, in reality, I'm writing not Rule Engine but our own system only with a lot of rules